Converting C# LINQ query to VB
I'm trying to convert a bit of code from C# to VB.NET that's looking for a specific set of class members and I've got it almost completely worked out except for a little LINQ query that uses some C# syntax with which I'm unfamiliar:
var members = entityType.GetTypeInfo().GetMembers(bindingFlags)
    .Where(m => m.MemberType == MemberTypes.Property || m.MemberType == MemberTypes.Field)
    .Select((m, i) => (member: m, positions: (user: resolver.GetPosition(m), builtin: i)))
    .Where(x => x.positions.user != -1)
    .OrderBy(x => x.positions)
    .Select(x => x.member)
    .ToArray();

The first .Where() bit makes sense and converts to:
.Where(Function(m) m.MemberType = MemberTypes.Property Or m.MemberType = MemberTypes.Field)

But, it's the first .Select() piece that I don't understand. It seems to be defining some labels (or perhaps a temporary structure of some sort) that it can pass along to the next .Where() clause. I've tried to define a function where I declare some variables with these names, but I can't figure out how to declare them:
.Select(Function(m, i)
            Dim member = m
            Dim positions As New Dictionary(Of Integer, Integer)(Resolver.GetPosition(m), i)
        End Function)

The types should be correct (both Integers), but obviously the attempt to just create a Dictionary(Of Integer, Integer) doesn't give me the ability to move into the next .Where() or the .OrderBy() clauses with the "names"/labels for user and builtin propegating.
Do I need to create/declare a Private Structure or something in the class that I can use in that query?

What you're seeing is Tuple syntax with named elements. It looks like VB.NET uses similar syntax, but with := instead of :. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/data-types/tuples

(Almost) never use Or but OrElse and And but AndAlso. You don't want to evaluate the second if the first already gave you the answer.

For whatever reason, I've never encountered "named tuples" (and few uses of tuples explicitly). Thank you for the explanation and link.

The syntax for initializing named tuples is slightly different in VB.NET:
Dim members As MemberInfo() = entityType.GetTypeInfo().GetMembers(bindingFlags).
    Where(Function(m) m.MemberType = MemberTypes.Property OrElse m.MemberType = MemberTypes.Field).
    Select(Function(m, i) (member:=m, positions:=(user:=resolver.GetPosition(m), builtin:=i))).
    Where(Function(x) x.positions.user <> -1).
    OrderBy(Function(x) x.positions).
    Select(Function(x) x.member).
    ToArray()


Apparently I didn't recognize it as a "named tuple". Thank you for the example.
